# I want to check if the website is ok

Tags: python, url, exception, web

I want to write a python code that checks if the website is up and running and if I type a random thing like "*whatever*" the program will say:

> "The website is not valid. Try another."

It will give me the ability to check another URL if the server is not up the program will say:

> "The website server is not up. Try another."

And again, check another URL.
I have tried for so long and always get an exception which I don't want to get, I want to change the exception to a print of my choice.

what I got so far is:

```
import urllib
print ("Which website would you like to check?")
website_url = raw_input("--> ")

#The user will stuck in a loop until a valid website is exist, using the Application protocol
while urllib.urlopen(website_url).getcode() != 200:
    print ("The website does not exist. Which website would you like to check?")
    website_url = raw_input("--> ")
```

Thanks for all the helpers :)

Comment: Have you written this program already? Is the problem simply that you want to change the error message? Can you show us what you have?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 just did :)

Comment: Which python version are you using? Python 3?

Comment: @svfat acctually I use PyCharm I am not sure about the version of the python but I installed python 2.7 in my computer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    import urllib    
    if website_url.split('//')[0] != 'http:' and website_url.split('//')[0] != 'https:':  # Adds http:// to the given URL because it is the only way to check for server response
        website_url = 'http://' + website_url
    while True: #The user will stuck in a loop until a valid website is exist, using the Application protocol
            try:
                if urllib.urlopen(website_url).getcode() != 200:
                    print ("Invalid URL given. Which website would you like to check?")
                    website_url = raw_input("--> ")
                else:
                    print ("The server is up")
                    break
            except:
                print ("Invalid URL given. Which website would you like to check?")
                website_url = raw_input("--> ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib
print ("Which website would you like to check?")
website_url = raw_input("--> ")
#The user will stuck in a loop until a valid website is exist, using the Application protocol
while True:
    try:
        if urllib.urlopen(website_url).getcode() != 200:
            print ("The website does not exist. Which website would you like to check?")
        else:
            print "site is up"
    except:
        print "Invalid URL given"
website_url = raw_input("--> ")
```

Comment: This code is good with an unvalid URL but if I try a URL like "www.google.com" the program says "Invalid URL given"

Comment: And the loop is non stopping, I want the loop to stop after a valid URL

Comment: Right, I think it is because the webserver isn't returning a 200 response code, but something redirect-related, maybe also check for 301 and 302?  As for stopping the loop, just add a break right after the "site is up" output.

Comment: LOL I FOUND THE ERROR!!! IF U ADD HTTP:// IT'S ALL WORKS OUT WITH YOUR CODE!! THANK U!!!